# JSF1091: No mime type could be found with url parameters

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I'm getting the dreaded JSF1091 warnings and hoping to find a solution. I use mojarra 2.1.29-11 on wildfly 10.1. I can avoid the error with myfaces, but myfaces has a different bug around the binding of datatable and other components that I need to avoid.

My jsf is pretty simple. This is in a column of a datatable

```
<h:outputLink value="admin_app_view.htm"  >
  <h:outputText value="#{entry.name}" />
  <f:param name="appId" value="#{entry.appId}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

For each row, I get this in the error logs:

```
09:58:34,192 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-59) JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file admin_app_view.htm?appId=233.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
09:58:34,193 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-59) JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file admin_app_view.htm?appId=234.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
```

and so on.

I'm sure I can get rid of this with log4j, but any of the experts know the right/best way to handle this? It's a legacy app being converted to mostly JSF, but some old JSP in places. I need to have the URL argument because this link takes me away from JSF pages to an old JSP page.

Thank you!

Comment: Tried doing what is mentioned in the warning?

Comment: Not sure how because the argument (appId=233) and so on can be any number. We already have a .htm with mime-type. This only happens when rendering an outputLink. I've heard this was fixed in 2.2 or 2.3, but since we can't upgrade, hoping for any other ideas of how to generate a link. Supposed old fashioned a href= might work, but is there a "proper" jsf way?